# Detect browser connection closed in PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, mod-php

Does anyone know if it is possible to detect whether the browser has closed the connection during the execution of a long `PHP` script, when using `apache` and `mod_php`?

For example, in `Java`, the `HttpOutputStream` will throw an `exception` if one attempts to write to it after the browser has closed it -- Or will respond negatively to `checkError()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [connection_aborted()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted.php)

Comment: It doesn't work in Fedora22, PHP 5.6.12 even when outputing data, and ignore_user_abort(false).

Answer (score 2):

In at least PHP4, connection_aborted and connection_status only worked after the script sent any output to the browser (using: flush() | ob_flush()).
Also don't expect accurately timed results.

It's mostly useful to check if there is still someone waiting on the other side.

Comment: `It's mostly useful to check if there is still someone waiting on the other side.`: how?

Comment: How: "echo" something or output a header(), 
call 'flush()' and then use you can get connection_aborted() to determine if the HTTP-client is still 'listening' or maybe timed out.

Answer (score 1):

http://nz.php.net/register-shutdown-function

Probably less complicated if you just want a script to die and handle it when a user terminates.

( Ie: if it was a lengthy search, this would save you a bunch of operation cycles )